# What is the best way to convert a scala array of strings to a map?

Tags: arrays, string, scala, lambda, hashmap

I have a array of strings which are delimited by a tab char ('\t'), after splitting by '\t' the second element is delimited by a ',' which are just a bunch of floats. What is a concise way to convert this string to a map?

```scala
val values = List("abc\t1,.2,.4", "def\t6,.2,2.4")
Map[String,Array[Float]] = Map{
                               "abc": [1,.2,.4],
                               "def": [6,.2,2.4]
                              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will work. Not a lot of checking for size or valid input so you'll have to add that yourself:

```
values.map{x =>
  x.split("\t").toList match {
    case x :: y :: Nil => (x -> y.split(",").map(_.toFloat).toList)}
}.toMap
```

Output:

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Float]] = Map(abc -> List(1.0, 0.2, 0.4), def -> List(6.0, 0.2, 2.4))
```

Comment: Good and beautiful !

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing below.

```scala
values.map(i => i.split('\t')).map(i => (i(0),i(1).split(',').map(_.toFloat))).toMap
```

output:

```scala
res30: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Array[Float]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a fairly straightforward approach:

```
val input = List("abc\t1,.2,.4", "def\t6,.2,2.4")

/* Split the strings into (k,v) tuples, (v is still a string) */
val split = input.map(x => {val spl = x.split("\t"); (spl(0), spl(1))})

/* Split the v's into a float array, transform (k,v) list into a map */
val output = split.map(x => (x._1, x._2.split(",").map(_.toFloat))).toMap
```

(the lines are split up for clarity)